# Login failed for user '' when connecting to SQL Server using Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database with Python using this code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
                  r'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'    
                  r'Server=12345.dcd_ba.weatherton.com;'
                  r'Database=Dentrix;'
                  r'Trusted_Connection=no;'
                  r'Integrated security=false;'
                  r'username=fred;'
                  r'password=test;'
                 )
return conn
```

But I am getting this error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

Comment: FYI, a trusted connection, and integrated security are the same thing; there's no point declaring both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Using Connection String Keywords with SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15)
it looks like you need to use `UID` instead of `username`

Comment: you are right @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I clarified my answer